# Android kotlin send email without internet connection

Tags: android, kotlin, email

I'm developing an app where I have to send several emails using SMTP without intent.  I would like to know if there is any way to send the emails even without internet connection, I mean, if there is no connection keep the email until the device gets the connection and then send inmediately.
I handle this issue by storing the info in a sqlite for "waiting emails" but it would be much easier for me if there is any way to do without code.
Any help?

Comment: How are you sending the emails today? Are you using the user's chosen email app and `Intent` actions like `ACTION_SENDTO`? Are you using JavaMail? Are you talking to your own Web service? Or are you doing something else?

Comment: I'm sorry for not be clear on my first message.  I'm usin javamail, I send by smtp without intent.

Comment: Then you will need to queue the emails yourself somewhere, or find some library that wraps JavaMail and offers that functionality.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, but I couldnt find any library to wrap JavaMail, hope it exists and someone knows it :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed createing a database with all the parameters needed on javamail.  Then I check if there are elements on the database everytime I go to the home page.